# How to display UILabel text of my TableView Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

[image]

I use Realm database here. I have a tableview controller that has a lot of UILabel, which I created by dragging from those Xcode UI emements. I tried using the data source method to display the UILabel text by setting cell = UILabel.text in this case. However, Xcode gives me an error saying that UILabel does not have attribute "text", which is different from what I see from the apple documentary.

What should I do in order to display those UILabel text on the TableView Controller. If I run my project on Xcode now, all the UILabel texts don't show up.

I thought I could use the following ways to display those UILabel text:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class NewIdeaCreation: UITableViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return ideaTable.count ?? 1
}

// Provide a cell object for each row.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTypeIdentifier", for: indexPath)

   // Configure the cell’s contents.
   cell.textLabel!.text = UILabel.text[indexPath.row]

   return cell
}
```

Comment: You should always add your code to make easier to help you. For example, do you a have a storyboard, xib or you UI is create programmatically? Where is the code to set UILabel text? Put your view controller here, your cell too. UILabel does have a text attribute, but how are you connecting your UILabel and your variable of type UILabel?

Comment: Thank you let me edit it better later on.

Comment: Hello. Just a clarification. When you say _I have a tableview controller that has a lot of `UILabel`_, I think you mean, your `UITableViewCell` has multiple labels, am I correct? Also do you have an array of items that you want to display in this table?

Comment: @Isuru Hello, yes the cell in UITableViewCell has multiple labels in it. They are organized by stackviews. I don't have an array of items. And I just added the picture of this tableview controller.

Comment: @Sammy I posted an answer below. I made a few assumptions regarding your Realm objects. If you can post that code too, then maybe I can update my answer to better suit your question.

Comment: Thank you @Isuru. I added the rest of the codes. I am making a habit tracker app. After I hit the "create" button located at the bottom of this controller, a new item would be generated in the previous TableView Controller. But for my problem here, does it have anything related to Realm?

Comment: @Sammy No no, your issue doesn't have anything to do with Realm. I just wanted to see your Realm object to make my answer clearer :)

Comment: In addition, shouldn't we set the cell.textLabel.text = UILabel.text? so that I can display those UILabel? Now if I run Xcode, all the UILabels are gone so the whole TableView Controller becomes empty. @Isuru

Comment: @Sammy Oh I think you've misunderstood the purpose of `UITableView`s as a whole. A tableview is usally used to display a list of somethings. Like if you have many habits you've already created and you want to show all of them in a list, you use a tableview. For something like a creation view such as this one, it's easier if you use a normal `UIViewController` where you can place `UITextField`s for users to input data.

Comment: @Sammy But if you have to use a tableview for this create habit form, look iinto static tableview. I found a [tutorial](https://manenko.com/2014/12/16/how-to-create-an-input-form-using-uitableview.html) where you can get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the `text` property of `UILabel`s directly since it's not a class property. `text` is an instance attribute. You first create an instance of `UILabel` and then set it's `text` value. Like so,

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Some text"
```

`UITableViewCell`s already have an instance of a `UILabel` called `textLabel`. You can set the value of its' `text` property like this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTypeIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell’s contents.

    // I'm assuming you have a Realm object called `Idea`
    // And `ideas` is an array of those `Idea` objects
    let idea = ideas[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = idea.name

    return cell
}
```